# Searching and Count records matching criteria in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

I'm trying to keep from getting errors in datatables if my search criteria is coming up with empty results.  Is there a way to get a count of the number of rows that is going to be returned in a table?

my table code looks like:

```
<% @loads.each do |load| %>
<% if load.trucker == current_trucker and (load.pickup_datetime <= Date.today or load.current_status == "ON HOLD")  %>
```

I'd just like to have a line ahead which checks to see if it is going to return 1 or more rows (so I can eliminate the results if it is null).

Any ideas? Go easy on me - I'm a hobby level guy.

Thanks

Comment: Include the error you are getting

Comment: The error I get is from datatables - "Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0."  It gives this if the criteria for the table is empty (null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping over all `@loads`, integrate the conditions into the query.  For example, *in the controller*,

```
@loads = @loads.where(
  'load.trucker == ? and (load.pickup_datetime <= ? or load.current_status == ?)', 
  [current_trucker, Date.today, 'ON HOLD']
)
```

Hopefully this fixes the problem in your view, though without the view code and a stack trace it's hard to debug.

At least, moving the database query to the controller is a step in the right direction.  It should be more performant and easier to test with a [controller test](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#controller-specs).